# Node path prefixes for modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

This should be a very simple question. I think it might be as simple as just being the convention, but I would like to check as I have no idea if there is anything else behind it or what phrases to even search regarding it.

```
var hello = require('./hello');
hello.world();
```

Imagine the above code. The require path is prefixed by a ./ this is always present for files in the same folder. Why not just the file name?

Comparitively the common use

```
var http = require('http');
```

Is not prefixed by a ./ I am currently assuming this is due to the http file being a "native" module. Therefore would I be right in saying that anything without ./ is looking in the native Node namespace and anything with a ./ is looking for a local file?

Also would a file in a higher directory like in PHP it would be ../
In Node would it be .././ or ./../

Comment: A file in a higher directory is what you would expect "../". The "./" is just a convention for files in the same directory.

Comment: This is really more of a *NIX convention than a node convention. If you list hidden files in any folder on a *NIX system (like MacOSX, Ubuntu, CentOS, etc) using the command `ls -a`, the top two 'files' listed will be `.`, which is a reference to the current folder, and `..`, which is a reference to the folder that contains the current folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a simple convention used in node. Please see the [module.require docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_require_id)

And for what it's worth, you won't always be using `require("./hello")`. Sometimes you'll be using `require("../../foo")` or `require("../")`.

---

Simply put,

- You use a `path` for requiring files within your module
- You use a string `identifier` for including other modules